# how to submit a form with multiple values

Tags: laravel

i have a form with the following

Item name 
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3

In the text field the input name of the field to handle the product name's is 'product_name';

How would you process a array and insert the  following item names into the database simultaneously when a user hit the submit button...

What I have tried hands on..

FORM IN MY VIEW

```
{{form::open(array('url' =>'batch', method=>'post'))}}
    <input type= "hidden" name="product_name" value="{{order->product_name}}
{{ form::close()}}
```

Controller

```
public function postBatch(){

    $posted = Input::get();

    foreach($posted as $ke=> $value){
        $batch = new Batch;
        $batch->product_name = $posted['product_name'];
     }

     $batch->save;

}
```

Results I had from this code

After I post the form only the 3rd item appears in my database ie. Only 'test 3' appears in my database was not sure all the names were posted so I set a function to count the items inserted and after that function I got to know  that it counts 3 bt I only see one name.

What I want to know

How can I post the form and all the products names will appear after been posted and save in the database.

Comment: you are creating batch object inside the for loop so after the termination fo the for loop only one batch object exsists that is the last one in the $posted array.
so try to put `$batch->save()` inside the for loop as the last statement :)

Comment: After I placed $batch->save() inside the loop again  only the last item 'test3' is reoccurring

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you're trying to do, I would re-think the logic a bit.

Pass an array of `products` as a property of `$order` to your view so they can be placed in separate hidden inputs.

**View:**

```
{{form::open(array('url' =>'batch', method=>'post'))}}
    @foreach($order->products as $product)
        Input::hidden('products[]', $product->name);
    @endforeach
{{ form::close()}}
```

Then, loop through the array of `products` using `create()`

**Controller:**

```
public function postBatch(){

    $products = Input::get('products');

    foreach($products as $product){
        Batch::create(['product_name' => $product]);
     }

}
```